# ggbiplot - change the colour of labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ggbiplot, princomp

By default, the ggbiplot function gives a graph with loadings as red arrows and unit labels in black:

```
library(ggbiplot)
data("USArrests")
us <- princomp(USArrests)
ggbiplot(us, labels = rownames(us$scores))
```

[image: Here] is the result of that code

How can I change the colour of these labels, and incidentally their size or font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggbiplot)
library(grid)
data("USArrests")
us <- princomp(USArrests)

# Cut the third score into 4 intervals using quantiles
cols <- cut(us$scores[,3], quantile(us$scores[,3], probs=seq(0,1,0.25)), include.lowest=T)

# Change label colors using the "group" option
# Change label font size using the "label.size" option
p <- ggbiplot(us, labels = rownames(us$scores), groups=cols, labels.size=4)

# Change label font family 
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
g$grobs[[6]]$children[[4]]$gp$fontfamily <- "mono"
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

To change label colors as a whole:

```
p <- ggbiplot(us, labels = rownames(us$scores), groups=1, labels.size=4) +
     theme(legend.position = "none")

# Change label colors 
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
g$grobs[[6]]$children[[4]]$gp$col <- "#FF9900"
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: I think what I was looking for were the _"group"_ and _"labels.size"_ options. Thank you!

Comment: update: in the end, "group" doesn't seem to be the right parameter, because you need, well, groups for it to work. i would like to change the colour of labels as a whole, not depending on a factor or values.
Maybe my question wasn't precise enough